# How animate D3 SVG bezier line for subtle wave effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm able to animate a curved line in like so:

```js
const svg = d3.select("#line-svg");
const lineWidth = 6;

// Scale.
const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("width"))]);
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 120])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("height")) - lineWidth]);

// Curved line interpolator.
const bezierLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x((d) => scaleX(d[0]))
  .y((d) => scaleY(d[1]));

// Draw line & animate.
svg
  .append("path")
  .attr(
    "d",
    bezierLine([
      [0, 40],
      [25, 70],
      [50, 100],
      [100, 50],
      [150, 20],
      [200, 130],
      [300, 120]
    ])
  )
  .attr("stroke", "url(#b1xGradient)")
  .attr("stroke-width", lineWidth)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .transition()
  .duration(900)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function () {
    const len = this.getTotalLength();
    return (t) => d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0")(t);
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="line-svg" width="100%" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="b1xGradient">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #18e589;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #2870f0;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

But how can I take these line points, or generate some line points, and then continually shift them subtly to create an animated wave effect?

P.S. The line doesn't have to look exactly like that either - it could be mathematically generated to be some kind of wavy line similar to the example (actually that'd be neat).

Something similar to this but more subtle range of movement and slower - https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-meshline-custom-spring-3-forked-og1f7?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by wave, but you can add a little bit of random offset to the line and redraw it infinitely many times. You can combine this with the growth animation by having named transitions - those can live side by side.

I assigned the data points using `.datum()` so I could access them inside the transition.

```js
const svg = d3.select("#line-svg");
const lineWidth = 6;

// Scale.
const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("width"))]);
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 120])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("height")) - lineWidth]);

// Curved line interpolator.
const bezierLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x((d) => scaleX(d[0]))
  .y((d) => scaleY(d[1]));

// Draw line & animate.
const line = svg
  .append("path")
  .datum([
    [0, 40],
    [25, 70],
    [50, 100],
    [100, 50],
    [150, 20],
    [200, 130],
    [300, 120]
  ])
  .attr("stroke", "url(#b1xGradient)")
  .attr("stroke-width", lineWidth)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return bezierLine(d); });

line
  .transition("grow")
  .duration(900)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function () {
    const len = this.getTotalLength();
    return (t) => d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0")(t);
  })

function wave() {
  line
    .transition("wave")
    .duration(900)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("d", function(d) { 
      // Add a little offset to each coordinate
      const offsetCoords = d.map(function(e) {
        return [
          e[0] - 3 + Math.random() * 6,
          e[1] - 2 + Math.random() * 2
        ];
      });
      return bezierLine(offsetCoords);
    })
    // Repeat
    .on("end", wave);
}

wave();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="line-svg" width="100%" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="b1xGradient">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #18e589;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #2870f0;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

---

**Edit** to make the line actually behave like a wave instead of pulsing, you might do something like this. It generates waves using a sine function, with random amplitudes, periods, and a random offset on the mean so it looks more chaotic. You can tweak the variables yourself, because it looks very different in the inline viewer than it does when editing - which I think has something to do with the width/height ratio.

In contrast to your example, it does not have waves extinguishing, only rolling in and out of view. However, this should be easy to implement, now that the wave generation has been taken care of.

```js
const svg = d3.select("#line-svg");
const lineWidth = 6;

// Scale.
const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("width"))]);
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 120])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("height")) - lineWidth]);

// Curved line interpolator.
const bezierLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x((d) => scaleX(d[0]))
  .y((d) => scaleY(d[1]));

// Create a sine wave. Each wave is completes a full number of periods
// before being replaced by another one
// if varyMean is true, add a little bit of noise to the mean of the function
function generateSine(y, step, mean, varyMean) {
  const sine = {
    amplitude: Math.random() * 5 + 20, // [5, 25]
    period: Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.05, // [0.05, 0.3]
    repeats: 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 3), // [1, 4]
    meanOffset: varyMean ? Math.random() * 50 - 25 : 0 // [-25, 25]
  };

  // Calculate a gradual decrease or increase the mean
  function offset(i) {
    return Math.min(i, 2 * Math.PI) * sine.meanOffset;
  }

  const offsetX = y.length * step;
  let runningX = 0;
  while (runningX < 2 * Math.PI * sine.repeats) {
    const m = mean + offset(runningX);
    y.push(m + sine.amplitude * Math.sin(runningX + offsetX));
    runningX += 2 * Math.PI * step / sine.period;
  }
}

// Draw line & animate.
const line = svg
  .append("path")
  .datum(function() {
    const domain = scaleX.domain();
    const nPoints = 50;
    const points = d3.range(nPoints).map(function(v) {
      return v / (nPoints - 1);
    });
    const step = points[1] - points[0];

    const x = points.map(function(v) {
      return domain[0] + v * (domain[1] - domain[0]);
    });
    const xStep = x[1] - x[0];
    
    // Draw two points just before and just after the visible part of the wave
    // to make the lines run smoothly
    x.unshift(x[0] - xStep); x.push(x[x.length - 1] + xStep);

    const y = [];
    const mean = d3.sum(scaleY.domain()) / 2;
    while(y.length < x.length) {
      generateSine(y, step, mean, true);
    }

    return {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      mean: mean,
      step: step
    };
  })
  .attr("stroke", "url(#b1xGradient)")
  .attr("stroke-width", lineWidth)
  .attr("fill", "none");

line
  .transition("grow")
  .duration(900)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
    const len = this.getTotalLength() * 2;
    return (t) => d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0")(t);
  })

function wave() {
  line
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return bezierLine(d.x.map(function(v, i) {
        // We store some additional variables at the end of y,
        // we don't want to show yet
        return [v, d.y[d.x.length - 1 - i]];
      }));
    })
    .datum(function(d) {
      const y = d.y;
      
      // Remove the y value that was just moved out of view
      y.shift();      
      // See if we still have enough y values left, otherwise, generate some
      while(y.length < d.x.length) {
        generateSine(y, d.step, d.mean);
      }

      return d;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      const step = d.x[1] - d.x[0];
      return `translate(${-scaleX(step)})`
    })
    .transition("wave")
    .duration(function(d) { return 5000 / d.x.length; })
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0)")
    .on("end", function() {
      // Repeat
      wave();
    });
}

wave();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>

<svg id="line-svg" width="100%" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="b1xGradient">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #18e589;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #2870f0;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the datum code and this kinda works but think I'll have to try for some kind of solution that moves the data points using some maths to create more of a wavy movement rather than random

Comment: If you update your question to be more specific, I'd be happy to update my answer

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this but I'm looking more for the wave to move like it would in the ocean - so a wave would move across the line and probably shrink in size as it does. Think it's quite an ask as will involve some mathematical sine-wave/oscillator type logic

Comment: e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-meshline-custom-spring-3-forked-og1f7?file=/src/index.js (but more subtle and slow)

Comment: So the current points of the line are not relevant?

Comment: Actually no, some randomness in the line would actually be a plus

Comment: Does [this](https://gist.github.com/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6) suit your needs? If not, can you explain what you would like to see differently?

Comment: Kind of like that except with more randomness in the size of waves and doesn't need to be along a straight line on the X

Comment: I proposed a new solution, I hope it is to your liking, but it's difficult because waves can behave in many different ways

Answer (score 1):

You can just reinitialize path points in the loop and transition between them.

I've just added changing of Y coordinates. You could play with round robin loop of X coordinates say to shift for 10% until it loops 10 times (and you reset the global counter variable back to 0 etc). That would make your desired wave (e.g. appearing to move to the right).

```js
const svg = d3.select("#line-svg");
const lineWidth = 6;

// Scale.
const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("width"))]);
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 120])
  .range([0, parseFloat(svg.style("height")) - lineWidth]);

// Curved line interpolator.
const bezierLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x((d) => scaleX(d[0]))
  .y((d) => scaleY(d[1]));

const randBezierLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x((d) => scaleX(d[0]))
  .y((d) => scaleY(d[1]*(1-(Math.random()+0.3)/5)));

const points = [
  [0, 40],
  [25, 70],
  [50, 100],
  [100, 50],
  [150, 20],
  [200, 130],
  [300, 120]
];

var lenTotal = 1200;// just more than gathered length
// Draw line & animate.
svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("id", "animLine")
  .attr(
    "d",
    bezierLine([
      [0, 40],
      [25, 70],
      [50, 100],
      [100, 50],
      [150, 20],
      [200, 130],
      [300, 120]
    ])
  )
  .attr("stroke", "url(#b1xGradient)")
  .attr("stroke-width", lineWidth)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .transition()
  .duration(900)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function () {
    const len = this.getTotalLength();
    return (t) => d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0")(t);
  });

function Transition() {
  d3.select("#animLine")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("d", randBezierLine(points))
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", lenTotal + ",0")
    .on("end", function() { Transition(); });
}

setTimeout(Transition, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="line-svg" width="100%" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="b1xGradient">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #18e589;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #2870f0;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Good idea think I will use and adapt this 